# iterarte over array and print collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, foreach

I have this array

```
var data=[{ id : 123, sourceid : '45dgd'},
{ id : 456, sourceid : 'shdjd'}]
```

my collection look like this

```
collection
{id: 3245, sourceid : '45dgd', status: 'Active'}
```

if I want to iterate this collection by array data and print status.
I am new to mongo. I know we can do this using foreach but I dont know how to exactly do it in mongodb
can anyone help me with this

Comment: you should indicate what language you are using to a better approach to your question

Comment: I want to query using robomongo

Comment: So, In that case, I  strongly recommend to read the documentation, has many examples and it is very easy to understand. [mongodb find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $in like so.

`{ "sourceid": { $in: ["45dgd","45dge"] } }`

This will fetch all the documents matching the sourceid.